# How can I define multiple SASS/SCSS variables at a time?

Tags: variables, sass

In-stead of defining multiple variables separately like:

```
$logo_text_color: $white
$menu_link_color: $white
$menu_icon_color: $white
```

Is there any way to define them together at a time; something like this?

```
$logo_text_color, $menu_icon_color, $menu_link_color: $white
```

Comment: Good question -- it would be convenient to do that, but no, as far as I know, it is not possible at the moment. And it is not possible to write a mixin to do it because variables are hoisted when sass compilation begins, so we cannot dynamically create variables.

Comment: It would make more sense if it was: `$logo_text_color: $menu_icon_color: $menu_link_color: $white;` because other languages allow variables to be set in this way like `x = y = z = 5` ....but unfortunately it's not possible :(

Comment: Finally I have found a solution, please check my shared answer...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution...

**SASS:**

```
=els($a: 1, $b: 2, $c: 3)
  height: $a + px
  width: #{$b}px
  content: abc
.cool
  +els
.things
  +els($a: 100)
.stuff
  +els($c: 29)
.other
  +els($c: 29, $b: 54)
```

**CSS:**

```
.cool {
  height: 1px;
  width: 2px;
  content: abc;
}
.things {
  height: 100px;
  width: 2px;
  content: abc;
}
.stuff {
  height: 1px;
  width: 2px;
  content: abc;
}
.other {
  height: 1px;
  width: 54px;
  content: abc;
}
```